# Form validation based on attribute type using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm working on form validations I want to validate fields based on attr(type) at one time all text field should be validated. like this, I want to validate

example

```
 if($(myForm + " input").attr("type") == "email") {
// Validate Email Here
 }
```

My code is working fine but here i can't do mutiple validations if i add one more extra field.can anyone help me how should i do validate as above i mentioned
Any help will be appreciated

```js
var Validator = function(form) {
    
    this.form = $(form);
    
    var Elements = {
        name: {
            selector: $('input[type=text]'),
            reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/
        },

        email: {
            selector: $('input[type=email]'),
            reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i
        },

        message: {
            selector: $('textarea'),
            reg: /^\s+$/
        }
    };

    var handleError = function(element, message) {
        element.addClass('input-error');
        var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
        var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
        error.appendTo($err_msg);
        element.keyup(function() {
            $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                element.removeClass('input-error');
            });
        });

    };

    this.validate = function() {

        this.form.submit(function(e) {

            for (var i in Elements) {

                var type = i;
                var validation = Elements[i];

                switch (type) {

                case 'name':
                    if (!validation.reg.test(validation.selector.val())) {
                        handleError(validation.selector, 'Not a valid name.');
                    }
                    break;
                case 'email':
                    if (!validation.reg.test(validation.selector.val())) {
                        handleError(validation.selector, 'Not a valid e-mail address.');
                    }
                    break;
                case 'message':
                    if (validation.reg.test(validation.selector.val()) || validation.selector.val() == '') {
                        handleError(validation.selector, 'Message field cannot be empty.');
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;


                }

            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });

    };
};

var validator = new Validator('#test');
validator.validate();
```

```css
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font: 76% Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form {
    margin: 1em 0 0 2em;
    width: 90%;
}

fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


label {
    float: left;
    width: 5em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
input {
    font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

fieldset ul li input {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0 0 7em;
}

form p input {
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}


div.error {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 5.3em;
    color: red;
    padding-right: 1.3em;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

.input-error {
    background: #ff9;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="test">

<fieldset>

<legend>Contact information</legend>


<div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</div>
 
<!--<div>
    <label for="lastname">LastName:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</div>-->

<div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    
</div>

<div>
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea>
</div>

<p><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" /></p>

</fieldset>


</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping over your form fields instead of your validators? The way that you made it now, you can only ever have as many fields as you have elements in the Elements object (currently 3). You should run through the form fields instead and pass each of them into the validator (might need a little rewriting).

Comment: @cjs1978 thanks can you help me how to do I'm new to jquery. actually, I tried in many ways but no luck .if you need to change code completely also no problem but the condition will be what I mention above.

Comment: You could go through the fields with something like $("form#test input").each(function(field){/* Validate the value of "field" in here  - you can use $(field).attr("type") to get the type, and $(field).val() to get the value, etc. */})

Comment: @cjs1978 I tried the above condition in the question but couldn't be achieved it. can you rewrite my above code?

Comment: No, I can't (don't have time now). But conceptually, you should imagine that your form could have 100 fields (which could in principle all be of the same type (i.e. all "name" fields) or a mix of types). Then, loop through the fields, and for each of them, check the type of the field, select the correct validation method (based on the type), and validate the field's value accordingly. You probably need to restructure your existing code a little bit.

Comment: @cjs1978 thanks. I said you already I'm new to jquery.i couldn't achieve it can you just help me to write loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172155/discussion-between-husna-and-cjs1978).

Comment: I ended up doing it, please see answer below.

Comment: @ cjs1978 I'm checking it out please be online.

Comment: Edited, please try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Working fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/oL4dr0fa/5/ - and also added some simple functionality in the submit handler to actually submit the form if there are no errors.

Here's the JS part, re. my comments above:

```
    var Validator = function(formObject) {
    this.form = $(formObject);

    var Elements = {
        name: {
            reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/,
            error: "Not a valid name.",
        },

        email: {
            reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i,
            error: "Not a valid e-mail address.",
        },

        message: {
            reg: /^(?!\s*$).+/,
            error: "Message field cannot be empty.",
        },
    };

    var handleError = function(element, message) {
        element.addClass('input-error');
        var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
        var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
        error.appendTo($err_msg);
        element.keyup(function() {
            $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                element.removeClass('input-error');
            });
        });

    };

    this.validate = function() {
            var errorCount = 0;
        this.form.find("input, textarea").each(function(index, field){
            var type = $(field).data("validation");
            var validation = Elements[type];
            if (validation){
                if (!validation.reg.test($(field).val())){
                        errorCount++;
                    handleError($(field), validation.error);
                }            
            }
        })
            return errorCount == 0;
    };
};

$(function(){
    $("form#test").on("submit", function(event){
        //event.preventDefault();
        return new Validator(this).validate(); // "this" here refers to the form

    })
})
```

Here's the edited HTML with data attributes:

```
    <form action="#" method="post" id="test">

<fieldset>

<legend>Contact information</legend>


<div>
    <label for="name">Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-validation="name" />
</div>


<div>
    <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-validation="name" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-validation="email"/>

</div>

<div>
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="15" data-validation="message"></textarea>
</div>

<p><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" /></p>

</fieldset>


</form>
```

Comment: this code is work like my previous code. only one text field is validated not all.

Comment: Edited, please give it another try

Comment: second input field not being validated.Even it is empty.

Comment: It does here. And also the third, fourth, etc. Do you have cached JS?

Comment: yes i did but its not working have a look https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/docnwwgc/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172160/discussion-between-husna-and-cjs1978).

Comment: @Husna, I have updated the example and also made a few other changes.

Comment: can you help me out how should i have to add other input fields like radio button, checkbox, select option.and after submit reset fields this is my updated code.https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/pKJzVL